# Router DNS timeouts

Tags: wireless-networking, router

The big issue is that I constantly have DNS timeouts when using my Buffalo WZR-300HP router (DD-WRT version "v24SP2-MULTI (07/09/12) std - build 19438"), both wired and wireless. I haven't figured out if this is time-based, or something to do with the connection, but I will get DNS timeouts for a few minutes, then things will clear up and I can browse again.

Does anyone have any idea what can cause this, or what settings I can check/verify? I use Comcast as my ISP, and have switched DNS to OpenDNS to see if that fixed it... it doesn't. If I connect directly to my cable modem everything works as expected.

Comment: Are you sure you have the current build of DD-WRT?

Comment: I had previously posted/answered that upgrading the firmware worked... that is actually not the case, as it started happening again. Any new ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this issue with two different routers (Draytek and Billion) but I'm not sure on the root cause. I would guess the DNS request being "proxied" via the router adds enough for a delay for sporadic timeouts.

What I did was set DHCP to give each client the DNS settings rather than for them to use the router as the DNS server.

Here, on my Billion, I have unchecked "Use Router as DNS Server" and let DHCP assign the servers:

[image: DNS Setting]